# Why do I need to use symbol-value inside mapcar to assign a value?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

If I have `x` initialized as

```
(setf x 0)
```

Then I can change the value directly by doing

```
(setf x 1)
```

So, when using `mapcar`, why do I have to use the `symbol-value` to assign to this symbol?

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (a b) 
            (setf (symbol-value a) b)) 
         '(x) 
         '(1))
```

Does it have something to do with the quote?

Comment: `(Setf x 0)` does _not_ initialize `x`.  It just sets it, and most implementations will implicitly initialize it but give a warning.  Don't do that.  Use something like `let` to establish local bindings.

Comment: This could be written `(mapcar 'set '(x) '(1))`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use setf for initialization, define variable by [`defvar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm) or [`defparameter`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm).

Second, you getting symbol 'X from your '(x), not a place, to use with `setf`, so you need to get place by symbol-value, then set it with setf macro.

Comment: @Toor_Sultan Note that this will only work with special variables (typically defined with def{var,parameter}).  You will *not* be able to do `(let ((x 0)) (mapcar ... '(x) '(1)))` to set the value of the variable established by `let`.